# Meaning of 'independence' in regression model

Tags: regression, independence

I am familiar with the following condition for statistical independence where $x$ and $y$ are two different (random) variables: 
\begin{equation}
E(xy)=E(x)\times E(y)
\end{equation}

Now, I came across a [paper](http://ideas.repec.org/a/taf/applec/v37y2005i11p1303-1311.html) (Appendix B, p.1311) where it mentions that if $h$ and $^{\partial h}/_{\partial z}$ are independent then following holds: 
\begin{equation}
E\left(h \cdot \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\right)=E(h)\times E\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\right)
\end{equation}

I would like to know: What does it mean if $h$ is a dependent, continuous variable--such as smoking expenditure (in dollars)--and $z$ is a continuous independent variable--say income in dollars--in regression model. Note that $^{\partial h}/_{\partial z}$ is the partial derivative of $h$ with respect to $z$ which is equal to $dh/h$ (percentage change in $h$)

Comment: Maybe you should provide the precise definition of $h$. The expectation of a derivative is a quite unusual thing.

Comment: @ Stephane : I have updated that; hope it is now more clear

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, [is it so unusual?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition) ;) user227710, it is unclear what the notation $E(h,\partial h/\partial z)$ means. In particular, the comma is confusing. Do you mean $E( h \cdot \partial h/\partial z)$? Also, if this is an ordinary linear regression model, the mean structure is fixed and the the error term is the only source of randomness, so if $z$ is independent of the error, then $\partial h/\partial z$ would be a fixed constant and can be pulled out of $E( h \cdot \partial h/\partial z)$. Is that what this question is about?

Comment: @ Macro :Yes I mean that (now updated). It's more complex that this. I have included the reference for the paper in the question.

Comment: $E(xy)=E(x)E(y)$ is zero correlation, not independence.

Comment: @Glen_b 's point is correct and seriously reorients the scope of this question. It's worth noting that only under a very strict assumption of jointly normally distributed variables does 0 correlation imply independence. Otherwise, independence is defined using the probability density. See Casella Berger (2001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marginal change of a variable w.r.t. to another variable cannot be equal to the corresponding percentage change of the former. The (point) percentage change equals the total differential of *the logarithm* of a variable, $dln(y) = dy/y$

The appendix you refer to writes (using your letters) $E[h\cdot (dh/h)]$, where $(dh/h)$ is the relative (marginal percentage) change in $h$ due to a change in some explanatory variable $z$. $d$ symbolizes total differential.

Then the paper says that if $h,\; (dh/h)$ are independent, then as usual the expected value can be broken.
For these two components to be independent, it must be the case that $h$ does not really appear in $(dh/h)$. This requires that $dh$ is a linear function of $h$, something like
$$dh = ahdz \Rightarrow dh/h = adz \qquad (\Rightarrow \frac{dh}{dz} = ah)$$

Related to the economic meaning of this, it is that the total marginal effect $z$ has on $h$ *depends on the level of $h$*.
Using your example, if $h$ is smoking expenditure and $z$ is income, then:

-if $a$ is positive, it would mean that the higher smoking expenditure is, the more it increases with income.

-if  $a$ is negative, it would mean that the higher smoking expenditure is, the less it increases with income.